# Cleaning local data from realtime-database remotely or after consecutive crashes

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

My realtime-database has data persistence for offline use and recently a recording error recorded a String as HashMap and consequently the application crashed for all my clients. I quickly corrected the error, but now all clients can no longer open the application, as it loads offline before online and ends up slowing down the error and closing the application for all users, or a good part of them.

I'm instructing them to do data wiping manually, but this is a big problem for me and I need to find a way to force this data wiping of all users remotely or predict in the application that when there are some crashes it will clear the local data automatically.

Any code suggestions or how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with an try/catch, like code below:

```
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        try {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class); // error occurs here
            //... some code ...// 
        } catch (DatabaseException databaseException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "DatabaseException ****** The read failed: " + databaseException);
            clearPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
            deleteCache(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled ****** The read failed: " + databaseError); }


public static void clearPreferences(Context context) {
    try {
        // clearing app data
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("pm clear "+context.getPackageName());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        deleteDir(dir);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}
```